# Forward declaring class, but Visual Studio ignoring it

Tags: c++

```
//Code for a simple game I am making
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Enemy;
class Player{
    public:
        int health=10;
        int damage=(rand() % 5);
        void attack(Enemy enemy, string log){
            enemy.health=enemy.health-damage;
            cout << "You dealt " << damage << " to enemy!" << endl;
        }
};
class Enemy{
    public:
        int health=10;
        int damage=(rand() % 5);
        void attack(Player player, string log){
            player.health=player.health-damage;
            cout << "Your enemy dealt " <<  damage << " to you!";
        }
};
Player p1;
Enemy e1;
```

Errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2027   use of undefined type 'Enemy'   Line 15
```

Can you help me solve this error?
I've just started programming 2-3 months ago.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to move definition of `Player::attack` after `Enemy`'s definition.

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't get you....

Comment: @Jarod42 But `Enemy` uses `Player`! To avoid the circularity, you'll need to move the definitions of those member functions that use the 'other' class to out-of-body, and after *both* classes have been defined.

Comment: By the way, neither of your `attack` functions make much sense, since they operate on copies - you very likely want them to operate on references to the original objects

Comment: I would suggest that you rethink your classes so as to avoid such circular references, use the power of the language - think of an abstract class with Enemy and Player being concrete implementations

Comment: The problem is that when the compiler sees line 15, it has no idea what `enemy.health` is. For example, it has no idea what type it is. Also, you modify the `health` element of the `enemy` that was constructed by the function call and then you throw that instance away, losing the modification.

Comment: `a = a - b;` can be rewritten as `a -= b;`.

Comment: Also, your `damage` members will be initialized only once per object, and the same value will be used each time the `attack` functions are called. Is that really what you want, or do you mean to put `damage` inside the `attack` functions, so that a new (random) value is used each time?

Comment: @ChrisBD as it stands Enemy and Player are basically the *same* class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forward declaration is used to break dependency cycle.

But declaration is not enough when you need **definition**, so you might need to move some stuff after both classes are defined.

In your case, it would be something like:

```
class Enemy;
class Player
{
public:
    int health = 10;
    int damage = (rand() % 5);
    void attack(Enemy& enemy);
};
class Enemy
{
public:
    int health = 10;
    int damage = (rand() % 5);
    void attack(Player& player)
    {
        player.health -= damage;
        std::cout << "Your enemy dealt " << damage << " to you!";
    }
};

inline void Player::attack(Enemy& enemy)
{
    enemy.health -= damage;
    std::cout << "You dealt " << damage << " to enemy!" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing argument by value needs definition. If you want to use:

```
void attack(Enemy enemy) {...}
```

to take enemy argument, you need to define Enemy first:

```
class Enemy {
...
};
void attack(Enemy enemy) {...}
```

Passign argument by reference or pointer however only needs declaration:

```
class Enemy;
void attack(const Enemy& enemy) {...}
// or
void collide(const Enemy* enemy) {...}
```

Jarod42's answer was right. I felt like giving a bit extra info about why and how you can use it if you really need to pass by value.